# 'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I am new in swift and now i am stuck in inheritance . Here i am using two class class A, and class B . Class B is inheriting some properties of class A . Here is the code .

```
class A
{
    var objRunningJobs:UIViewController!
    var objCompletedJobs:UIViewController!
    init(objRunningJobs:UIViewController, objCompletedJobs: UIViewController) {
        self.objRunningJobs = objRunningJobs
        self.objCompletedJobs = objCompletedJobs
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class B: A
{
    override init(objRunningJobs:UIViewController, objCompletedJobs: UIViewController) {
        super.init(objRunningJobs: objRunningJobs, objCompletedJobs: objCompletedJobs)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

In class A , after init i am getting the error of **'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer .**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. What is the superclass of `A`? It should have one.

Comment: If the A class extends ViewController then the superclass is the ViewController class. If not then the super class is the Object class

Comment: class A: UIViewController {}

Comment: Then you got your answer. It should work, can you write me the code that you use for the initialization?

Comment: O! try to delete the override from the B class initializer

Comment: Why downvote now?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463685/swift-super-init-isnt-called-on-all-paths-before-returning-from-initializer?noredirect=1#comment93799523_53463685

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
class A: UIViewController {
let objRunningJobs: UIViewController
let objCompletedJobs: UIViewController

init(objRunningJobs:UIViewController, objCompletedJobs: UIViewController) {
    self.objRunningJobs = objRunningJobs
    self.objCompletedJobs = objCompletedJobs
    super.init(nibName: "TestNib", bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Replace 'TestNib' with yours.
But it's a bad way to initialize UIViewController subclass.
Probably, you don't understand role of UIViewController's and their hierarchy. What you want to do in your app?