# Swift: 'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I am getting this error on the last brace of a init in a class of mine. The class looks something like the following (I market the spot where error happens):

```
class RecordingViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    let cameraButton:UIButton?
    let camPreview:UIView?

    init (cameraButton: UIButton!, camPreview: UIView!) {
        self.cameraButton = cameraButton
        self.camPreview = camPreview

    } //get error here

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //do a bunch of other stuff
}
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578538/super-init-isnt-called-on-all-paths-before-returning-from-initializer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873071/hello-i-want-to-create-constructor-for-my-class-and-i-have-an-error-super-init) for a solution but both seem like solutions that are either really bad or that are too specific to that question, thus they have not work for me.

I was hoping for a solution to my problem done in such a way that it can help me understand why this error is happening.

Comment: Please read the [Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) chapter in the Swift book.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since you inherit from UIViewController, you should call `super.init` right after you set the variables in your `init` function

When you inherit a class and implement a new init function or override its own init function you should (almost) always call super.init. Let's take your example, you inherited from UIViewController. UIViewController has a few init functions that you can use to initialize a view controller. if you don't call super.init, all the code inside those functions will not get called and possibly the view controller won't get initialized.

Anyway, this piece of code should work for you:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button: UIButton?

    init(button: UIButton) {
        self.button = button
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: why tho? plz add full explanationas the question requests and then I can accept answer

Comment: When you inherit a class and implement a new init function or override its own init function you should (almost) always call `super.init`. Let's take your example, you inherited from `UIViewController`. `UIViewController` has a few `init` functions that you can use to initialize a view controller. if you don't call `super.init`, all the code inside those functions will not get called and possibly the view controller won't get initialized.

Comment: Also, why would you pass a button and a view to a viewcontroller? seems like something you shouldn't do

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? "seems like something you shouldn't do"

Comment: I get Ambiguous use of 'init' . when I just paste it into the init

Comment: You probably want to pass around models and not views.

Comment: Are you using xib/storyboard or just code for this ViewController?

Comment: This VC only uses code, although some code is dependednt on buttons which is why I try and . transfer those buttons from another VC

Comment: I accepted your answer but I am just wondering- why is it that when I have this super.init after all the stuff I do inside that it works fine... but If I make it the first statement that it says "Property 'self.cameraButton' not initialized at super.init call" and "Immutable value 'self.cameraButton' may only be initialized once"

Comment: When you declare `let` constants you have to set them up before calling the `super.init` constructor. `let` means they have a constant value, therefore they need to be set up first. Maybe change your `let`s to `var` so you could set them up later. or maybe pass them after the ViewController has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I found on Swift Programming Language:

> In the first phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the new instance is considered ready for use.
>
> A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.

Hope this can explain that question.